# Typescript error - No overload matches this call

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to add typescript types to exist project.
Progress is a number that define length to progressbar

```
interface ProgressProps {
  comp: JSX.Element;
  progress?: any;
}

export const Progress: React.FC<ProgressProps> = ({ progress }: any) => {
  return (
    <StyledProgressBlock progress={progress}>
      <span className="progress-line__value">{progress}%</span>
    </StyledProgressBlock>
  );
};

const StyledProgressBlock = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: ${props => props.progress && props.progress}%;
`;
```

I get error underlined this property: progress={progress}
Please help to solve it and give the link to good explanation to solve this trouble in future.

Comment: Can you show how you have use the Component

Comment: just import to another component and render: <Progress progress={progress} />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to specify type like this:

```
const StyledProgressBlock = styled.div<{ progress: number }>`
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: ${props => props.progress && props.progress}%;
`;
```

Comment: Great thanks! As I understood we need to pass type of added attribute to div, it is not clarify yet, but works fine!

Comment: Yes, if the progress prop is optional, don't forget to put optional(?) over there